# Python - UnboundLocalError: local variable 'health' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, local

Despite importing the variable 'health' from a different module, the function below provides the error shown in the title. 'Health' is also globalised and I have removed both the globalisation and the importation of the variable and I still receive the same error.

Below is the function that is causing the issue.

```
def combat():
    enemy_health = (random.choice(random_enemy_Health))
    enemy_attack = (random.choice(random_enemy_Attack))
    print("\nYou are fighting a" ,random.choice(enemies), "with an attack amount of" ,enemy_attack, "and a health amount of" ,enemy_health,".")
    while health > 0 and enemy_health > 0:
        if turn == 1:
            while loop == False:
                response=input()
                try:
                    move = response("Do you want to attack or flee? Type '1' to attack and '2' to flee.")
                    move = int(move)
                    if move == 1:
                        enemy_health = enemy_health - attack
                        print("You attacked!")
                        loop = True                       
                    elif move == 2:
                        hub_travel()
                        print("You fled the battle, come back once you are stronger!")
                        loop = True
                    else:
                        print("Invalid number, try again")
                        continue
                except:
                        print("Invalid number, try again")
                        continue
            turn = 2                                                    

        if turn == 2:
            AImove = randint(1,2)
            if AImove == 1:
                print ("Enemy attacked!")
                health = health - enemy_attack
            turn = 1                                                    
            continue

    print ("game over!")

    if enemy_health == 0:
        print("The enemy has been defeated!")
        gold += random.choice(gold_dropped)
```

The error occurs on this line in particular:

```
while health > 0 and enemy_health > 0:
```

Comment: You have to assign `health` a value before checking if it is greater than zero.  You aren't doing that.  The error message seems pretty clear to me...

Comment: If you need the value of `health` which is owned by another module, you need to either pass it in as a parameter from a function call that has access to that value, or you need to provide this module with a way to call on that value. For example, you might have an object which maintains the state of `health`, in which case you can access it directly or provide an accessor function.

Comment: In this case, with `health` being an intrinsic characteristic of something like a character, you would do best to provide a Character object which, rather than reporting out its `health`, would provide some way for another object to hit it. Then the Character would be responsible for applying the damage to itself and, for example, dying if health < 0 or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, instead of relying on globals, I would use parameters. This advice may help you to track some errors.

Globals variables is a possibility in programs that have a few lines of code. But, when you application grows, it is a bit hard to track the current value of some variable, because it can be used in several functions or methods (probably, you need a mental mapping to find out the current value). So, this is one of the reasons why you must prefer to use local variables or parameters instead of globals.

Comment: I am a very basic coder and the brunt of what I know comes from compulsory lessons so I am yet to understand the logic behind parameters and how they work in the sense you are are describing. Can you elaborate on this further please?

Answer (score 0):

This change would allow your function to work the way you want:

```
def combat(health):
    ...
```

Of course, you'd have to find the places where you call the function and pass in the value for `health`. I don't know if the code at that point has access to that information.

This is probably the simplest fix that could possibly address this issue. It is certainly not the best fix, but this is not a good place for an architecture tutorial.

Comment: It works as intended, didn't realise how simple the fix was! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad I could help.